# How to get Unity Dash Source code and compile it

Tags: unity

Hey Guys I am trying to create a Desktop environment using compiz as windows manager and docky and I want Unity Dash as the default app launcher so I want to know how to get unity dash source and compile it.

Comment: https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity/